# Storing Json value in add_post_meta

Tags: php, json, wordpress, variables

How can I store this Json value in add_post_meta

```
  $offer_name= $item['data'][$i]['Offer']['name'];

  add_post_meta($post_id, 'offer_name', $offer_name);
```

The json value of $offer_name doesn't get stored but normal string get stored.

Update 1: this is how I tested .

case 1 // With json the value doesn't  get stored..

```
 $offer_name= $item['data'][$i]['Offer']['name']; 

echo $offer_name; // the value gets echoed .

 add_post_meta($post_id, 'offer_name', $offer_name); // the value of $offer_name doesn't  get stored
```

case 2 // without json the value get stored..

```
  $offer_name="My  Name"; 

 add_post_meta($post_id, 'offer_name', $offer_name); // the value of $offer_name does get stored
```

Update 2: if i store the json data in  "{ }"  then the value get stored in WordPress

```
$offer_name ="{$item['data'][$i]['Offer']['name']}";


add_post_meta($post_id, 'offer_name', $offer_name);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, is the JSON value or string or not? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: if i echo   $offer_name it shows the echo the value. But its not getting stored in custom field.. But if store a  string eg=  $offer_name 'my name'; ;the value get stored in custom field.

Comment: That seems very odd: I don't think the problem lies with the JSON per se, since `add_post_meta()` will accept mixed variables no problem. You might need to post more of your code. How are you checking if it's being stored? Are you just echoing it our or are using `print_r()` or `var_dump()`?

Comment: i used echo ,print_r() and var_dump() . and it shows the value.. but it couldn't be stored in the custom field..

Comment: I meant how are you checking that it's being stored or not? You need to verify if it really isn't being stored, or if it isn't fetching it properly, or if it isn't displaying it properly. Those are three different problems that will all display the same symptoms.

Comment: i updated the question . take a look thank in advance

Comment: Can you also show where you're using `get_post_meta()`; your example still doesn't show where you're checking if the value is being stored or not.

Comment: i check it in wp dashboard.

Comment: please take a look at new update.

Comment: can you do a `print_r($item)` and show the results?

Comment: see the results at http://pastebin.com/ZLxfXSxv

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). This will return a JSON formatted string which you can use to save in your database.

Note that with characters such as ë, â, Æ etc you should use [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on your JSON encoded string before you attempt to save it in the database. This way once you decode the JSON string these special characters can be seen properly.

(Yes this is **very** old but I am searching for something myself and thought why not eh?)

Comment: You deserve metal for this :) , without addslashes(), my new line characters '\n' ended up as cassual letter 'n' after decoding.

Comment: Note, that the recommended function to use for JSON or simmilar data in postmeta is `wp_slash()`. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#character-escaping

Comment: its 2 years ago i found this on google and u both saved me.